# Is the zero of a field irreducible?

Tags: ring-theory

Definition1: An element $a$ of an integral domain $R$ is irreducible
if it is not a unit and if $a=bc$ implies that $b$ is a unit or
$c$ is a unit.

Definition2: An element $a$ of an integral domain $R$ is irreducible if
ideal $\left(a\right)$ is maximal *among the proper principal ideals*, i.e. if
$\left(a\right)\subseteq\left(b\right)$ implies that $\left(b\right)=\left(a\right)$
or $\left(b\right)=\left(1\right)$. (originally the word *proper* was forgotten by me)

Question:

> Which one to choose?

I thought they were both the same until I discovered that according to the second definition $0$ is irreducible in the special case that $R$ is a field. According to the first definition $0$ is not irreducible. This because $0=bc$ is true for the non-units
$b=c=0$.

Comment: Take the first. $0$ should not be considered irreducible.

Comment: I've always included non-zero in the conditions for definition $1$. This is what is done in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, as well as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element).

Comment: Well, @MichaelAlbanese, let's not forget that Wikipedia definitions are often the product of history, especially with things like ring axioms where even professionals cannot agree on whether to always have a $1$ or not. :-)

Comment: As @MichaelAlbanese said, the usual variant of Def1 includes the condition that $a$ be non-zero. A related confusion may occur with *prime* in place of irreducible: We speak of a prime *element* only if it is nonzero, but the zero ideal is counted as prime *ideal*.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese why including the non-zero demand by def1? If $a$ is irreducible according to def1 then it follows that $0$ is non-zero, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When studying factorization theory in *domains*, one is usually not interested in the trivial factorizations of $\,0,\,$ so one employs a definition of irreducible that proves most *convenient* for theorems about factorizations of other (nonzero) elements. So, to avoid exceptional cases, and to avoid having to frequently write "nonzero irreducible", it is convenient to exclude $\,0\,$ from the set of irreducible elements. Your first definition does this. It is probably an oversight the the second definition does not also exclude $\,0\,$ (probably "maximal among *proper* principal ideals" was intended - as is often written).

In contrast, when studying factorization theory in commutative rings *with zero-divisors*, the factorizations of $\,0\,$ are less trivial, yielding information about the zero-divisors, so they may prove of interest. So here one has to be more careful about formulating a good definition of irreducible. For example, see the definition of associate and irreducible in the paper below, where it turns out that, for all $3$ notions of "irreducible" (based on $3$ notions of "associate"), one has $\,0\,$ is irreducible iff the ring is a domain (see the paragraph following Definition $2.4).$

[Factorization in Commutative Rings with Zero-divisors.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181072068)
D.D. Anderson, Silvia Valdes-Leon.
Rocky Mountain J. Math. Volume 28, Number 2 (1996), 439-480

Comment: Thank you. This makes me 'well-informed'. I indeed forgot the word 'proper' in my question.